# conda-build fails to recognise libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, conda-build

I am trying to build a package using conda-build. This is my first time trying to build a conda package, and I am having far more problems than I expected too.

Here is my build.sh

```
CMAKE_PLATFORM_FLAGS+=(-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="${RECIPE_DIR}/cross-linux.cmake")
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_FLAGS[@]} .
make
cp surveyor.py random_pos_generator.py $PREFIX/bin/
cp add_filtering_info call_insertions clip_consensus_builder dc_remapper filter normalise reads_categorizer $PREFIX/bin/
```

And here is my meta.yaml:

```
{% set name = "insurveyor" %}
{% set version = "1.0.1" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  url: https://github.com/kensung-lab/INSurVeyor/archive/refs/tags/1.0.2.tar.gz
  sha256: 33c85157892d3256abc96bb2a9053f05da9dcf55befeed720e965577db0b78b5

build:
  skip: True # [not linux]
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    - cmake >=3.5
    - autoconf ==2.69
  host:
    - libcurl
    - bzip2
    - xz
    - zlib
    - libdeflate
    - openssl 
    - htslib >=1.13
  run:
    - python
    - numpy >=1.21.2

test:
  source_files:
    - demo/

about:
  home: https://github.com/kensung-lab/INSurVeyor
  summary: 'An insertion caller for Illumina paired-end WGS data.'
  description: XXX
  license: GPL-3.0-only
  license_file: LICENSE

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - Mesh89
```

And here is the output of the process:

https://justpaste.it/3gfzf

(stack overflow would think the log is spam)

There are plenty of worrying messages, for example:

```
Warning: rpath /home/user/anaconda3/conda-bld/insurveyor_1670384223059/_build_env/lib is outside prefix /home/user/anaconda3/conda-bld/insurveyor_1670384223059/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_ (removing it)
Unknown format
```

```
WARNING :: Failed to get_static_lib_exports(/home/user/anaconda3/conda-bld/insurveyor_1670384223059/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_/lib/libssl.a)
Unknown format
```

`Binary doesn't have a program header`

When I try to run any executable, I get

```
symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
```

I have spent a long time trying to figure out what is wrong and I am completely lost. When I google the warning/error messages, I cannot find any results.
I wonder if there is something fundamental that I misunderstand about the build process.
For example, why does conda complain about the rpath of the executables pointing to the build environment? Why those "Unknown format" warnings regarding the static libraries?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue for the same library that is missing. When using cmake and even when running a git clone command. Any progress on the issue?

Comment: Hi, I face same issue during a git clone by cmake. Do you have news on this?